GoogleSignIn with Firebase and Streamlit
Does anyone has an idea how can I implement Google Sign In and combine it with Firebase with Streamline or any other python framework. I found a solution for login with email and pass in streamline, and also a solution to sign up with google, but this one does not go through Firebase Authentication.
